# identical css in child not overriding parent

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm building a wordpress site based on my own child theme of Flaton.
The nav container is set to width 93% in the parent with the following code:

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container { width: 93%; }
  /* more stuff */
}
```

I would like to change it to 100% so I have copied the exact code above to the very end of my own style.css file.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container { width: 100%; }
}
```

However it is not working. When I inspect the element I see the parent css but not the child. My css is being recognized for other overrides elsewhere though.

Comment: Can you increase the specificity of your override?

Comment: Yes I can (although previous attempts failed). If I use #site-navigation .container it works. The million dollar question is why is it necessary?

Comment: Can you link to your page?

Comment: Check the order in which the files are being loaded. It may be that the parent css is being loaded after the child css (sounds crazy, but anything can happen in wordpress themes).

Comment: sorry @uom-pgregorio the site is still local

Comment: @groooves OP has indicated that some of his/her overrides are being respected so I think the order in which they are loaded should be okay.

Comment: @groooves how do I do that?

Comment: need live example

Comment: Inspect the source code on the browser and see which CSS File comes first. CSS is loaded in the order in which they're linked in the resulting html.

Comment: @groooves, yes of course! The parent css is loading first

Comment: @marcp It's going to be hard for us to help you unless we can see what is happening. Problems like these we need either a live page or a Fiddle playground showing the problem.

Comment: One issue could be that the browser was caching the previous version of the css file. In that case, the problem should be gone now.